# TeXMaker Table of contents not available when PDF viewer is not embedded

Tags: texmaker

In TeXMaker 4.4.1 the interface allows to jump to pages in the output PDF and even navigate by the table of contents with the embedded PDF viewer (see picture). However, when the PDF viewer is not embedded, this options are completely gone. How can I access this options without embedding the internal PDF viewer?

[image: Texmaker embedded PDf viewer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is a little hidden in the menu under `view > pages` or `view > structure`. This will open a side bar where one can choose between getting an overview of the pages or the structure of the document.